# Array operations and loops on MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new in Assembly and I need some help through a C loop to convert it into MIPS code. I have the following loop:

```
int A[40], B[40], i;
for (i=1; i < 40; i++) {
    B[i] = A[i] + A[i-1];
    A[i] = 5*B[i] ;
}
```

I dont have any clue about array operations with changing variables such as i in this example.

Comment: Show us what you have so far for your MIPs Assembly.

Comment: I actually have nothing.. I am using a disassembler https://gcc.godbolt.org/ but still it is quite complex to understand

Comment: I'd start with the fundamentals - Variable Declaration, basic actions, and build up towards what you are looking for.  Looping structures with counters take some understanding to make work in Assembly, so get more basic pieces in place and you'll build towards it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont have any clue about array operations with changing variables such as i in this example.

Just do what the C code says and don't worry about the fact that the array contents are changing during the loop.  For `B[i] = A [i] + A[i-1]` ===> compute i*4+A, load that, compute (i-1)*4+A, load that, add them together, compute i*4+B, store the add result there...

After a bit you may see that `A[i]` and `A[i-1]` and `B[i]` can share some of the address computation (e.g. they all use i*4), but that is not necessary as a first step — so, just do what the C code says: translate each little piece literally.  Your first objective is to get assembly to work the same as the C — don't try to optimize the C algorithm while translating into assembly.

If you want to optimize the algorithm, do that in C first, *and then* translate that into assembly.

In assembly you'll see some micro optimizations, so you can do a few more machine code optimizations after translation into assembly, but that is probably not where you should be optimizing the algorithm itself.

---

To give you an idea of how we might optimize this in C:

```
int A[40], B[40], i;
for (i=1; i < 40; i++) {
    int temp = A[i] + A[i-1];
    B[i] = temp;
    A[i] = 5*temp;
}
```

We do little changes like the above.  And then maybe:

```
int A[40], B[40], i;
int lastA = A[0];
for (i=1; i < 40; i++) {
    int temp = A[i] + lastA;
    B[i] = temp;
    lastA = 5*temp;
    A[i] = lastA; 
}
```

These local variables `temp` and `lastA` will work quite well in MIPS assembly, a CPU register for each.